Unitary invariance of the Gaussian Unitary Ensemble
I'm stuck with a property of a GUE matrix. In the textbooks it is claimed to be "obvious" but I can't figure out why.
Suppose we have a GUE matrix $G$ and a unitary matrix $U$. Then $UGU^{-1}$ should be equal in distribution to $G$. But why doesn't this property hold for all regular matrices? Using the density
$$ C\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}Tr(G^2)\right) $$
of the GUE, it should follow that
$$Tr((UGU^{-1})^2)=Tr(UG^2U^{-1})=Tr(G^2)$$
for all regular $U$. So why does $U$ necessarily have to be unitary?

The change of variables also needs to include the Jacobian.

Because the trace is invariant wrt rotation of factors in product arguments $$\text{Tr}( a \ b  \  c) = \sum_{ikl}a_{ik}\ b_{kl}\ c_{li} = \sum_{ikl} c_{li}\ a_{ik}\ b_{kl} $$
so with $U^\star = U^{-1}$
$$\text{Tr}(U^\star \ G  \ U  \ U^\star \ G  \ U )= \text{Tr}(U U^\star \ G  \ U \ U^\star  G) = \text{Tr}(G^2) $$

Yes, but why do we have to assume that U is unitary?

The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. They are independent of the representation wrt to unitary group of basis transforms, that are arbitrary

But the proof you gave above doesn't require the matrix to be unitary, right? It would work with any regular (not necessarily unitary) matrix U?
